# Libgdx - game closing immediately after start when using Screen

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to get my main class to setscreen to my gamescreen class.when I try to run the desktop application the only thing that happens is that a window with a black background opens and stays up for half a second and then closes down and I have no idea why it doesn't work. I'm using Netbeans if that has anything to do with it.

Here is my main class:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

    public SpriteBatch batch;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        this.setScreen(new GameScreen(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();
    }
}
```

and here is my screen class:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen{
Texture texture;
private MyGdxGame game;
public GameScreen(MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    texture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
}

@Override
public void show() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void render(float f) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
game.batch.begin();
game.batch.draw(texture, 0, 0);
game.batch.end();
}

//I havn't touched the other methods so I didn't paste them.
```

I haven't touched the desktop class.

I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at com.mygdx.game.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:27)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:14)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Comment: It looks like your `GameScreen.show()` method, which throws the `UnsupportedOperationException`, is being called; does providing a proper implementation for that method help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically throwing an exception in method show(), which is called right after setting the screen to MyGdxGame class.

```
@Override
public void show() {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}
```

Never used NetBeans, but it looks like it overrides show() with an exception. As the comment in the code suggest, change the body of generated methods in Tools | Templates to avoid this kind of errors.

Comment: Netbeans, by default (I don't know if you can change it), will add that extra line when you ask it to auto correct you. What he may have done was typed up the first line "public class GameScreen implements Screen{   }" and then asked netbeans to generate the rest of the class for him with the lightbulb that shows up at the side of the row.

Comment: Thank you it works now. never had this problem before so I didn't know what to do